# sorting character array using sort()

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to sort char array like this:

```
#include<algorithm>
...
char x[] = "coast";
sort(x, x+5);
std::cout<<x;
```

But it displays garbage. Integer arrays are sorted properly however.

Comment: Just to be complete you have to do std::cout<<x<<std::endl; so you flush buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine over here

```
[~]> clang++ test.cpp
[~]> ./a.out 
acost
```

Comment: Er, gcc 4.4.3 on ubuntu 10.4 doesnt do it properly.

Comment: @Abhi: Please paste the exact and full program (`main()` and all) you tried, and (if possible) the exact result. This __should__ work.

Comment: Works with gcc 4.4.1 on Ubuntu 9.10

Comment: Actually, in the code there are other things which i had to comment out. Now it works with only those statements. Thanks.

Comment: @Abhi: Which is exactly why you need to create a proper repro case that we can paste into our editors and try ourselves. IMO, in 80% of all cases you find your problem while you create that repro case. For the other 20% you have a perfect piece of code to ask about.